# Trying to insert array to database without getting repetition

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My english is not the best so I will try my best apologize if confusing.Anyways I am making a game where everyone is assigned a role.The problem I have is everytime it inserts into the database there a repetitive not in the name but number when it comes to array[].

```
<?php
include_once('database.php');
$roles = array('cop','cop','robber','robber','gangster','gangster');
$array = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `account`");
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

shuffle($roles);
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $realrole = $roles[$i];
    $name = $array[$i]['name'];
    echo("   ".$realrole);
    $sq = "UPDATE account SET role = '$realrole' WHERE name = '$name'";

}
mysqli_query($db,$sq);
```

I spent long hours on this and I am still new hope it make sense thank you

Comment: Can you provide what is inside `$array`?

Comment: Also, why do you execute the update query outside the for loop? It will only update last one.

Comment: What you mean by "there a repetitive"

Comment: @rcs ..I think $array holds accounts of users

Comment: @rcs inside the $array are the accounts in the database

Comment: @hanish singla lets say in an array theres $array = array(cop,cop,robber) What I am getting for ex is like $array[1] $array[0] $array[1] what I want is $array[1] $array[2] $array[0] no matter what if it make sense.It is the element of the array that i want not to repeat itself not the name itself

Comment: @rcs what would I have to do to prevent it from updating

Comment: But why you want $array[0] and $array[1] ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178427/discussion-between-hanish-singla-and-sang-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should solve your issue

```
<?php

include_once('database.php');
$roles = array('cop','cop','robber','robber','gangster','gangster');
$array = array();

shuffle($roles);

$sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `account`");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

$i=0;
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $realrole = $roles[$i];
    $name = $array[$i]['name'];
    echo("   ".$realrole);
    $sq = "UPDATE account SET role = '".$realrole."' WHERE name = '".$name."'";
    mysqli_query($db,$sq);
}
```

Comment: Its weird because it would be correct when you echo it out but when it goes into the database it still repeating a few things in the array

Comment: Can you paste the output and how you need it. It will help to understand your problem better